# Reutilizing gulpfile in future projects

Tags: git, terminal, gulp, package.json

I am working on web tooling and automation and I am wondering if there is a way of reusing the gulpfile I used in past projects in a new project without having to install every tool again.

Some told me to copy and paste the gulpfile.js and packgage.json onto the new project but that did not work for me.

I woudl appreciate any ideas. 
Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can accomplish this by copying the node_modules carpet as well as the json.package and the gulpfile.js and pasting it into your new project's directory.
json.package tells what software to install, the gulpfile configures that software.
The node_modules is the directory for the build tools or packages the json.package installed.